# Remmina remote terminal window is all black, although connection was successful

Tags: remmina

I have 2 Ubuntu 14.04 boxes configured with SSH, X11VNC. I have previously successfully achieved a remote desktop session using Remmina. Now whenever I connect, I only see a window with the client area all black.
[image: Remmina black screen]

The host server shows that I am successfully connected (per /var/log/auth.log). I've tried different resolutions and get the same result.

A few days ago I performed the recommended SW updates on the host server box. Perhaps this changed some configuration file.

Answer (score 6):

I discovered that the reason I was getting the black window was because there were 2 simultaneous users logged-into the host server.

It would not work (black display on client) if:
- 2 users were logged-in regardless of which user had the primary display, or
- only 1 user was logged-in but was screen-locked and had not been re-assigned the primary display (had not unlocked the display since the 2nd user had used the display).

Conversely, the remote display would work if:
- only 1 user was logged-in AND that user either [did not have screen lock engaged OR [had locked the screen AND no other user had logged-in since the user had engaged screen lock]].

I wonder if this is explained in a man page somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Right click > Edit > Advance settings > Set "Quality" to "Best (slowest)"

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer 8 years after the question, because it literally just fixed me up when I updated to Ubuntu 23.10 :)